# Unable to delete unwanted docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, operating-system, system, docker-command

I want to remove all the unwanted docker images and containers from my system's `C:` drive. Currently system running out of memory. I had used the commands but it's showing the following error:

```
error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.40/containers/prune: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

How do I resolve it?
image1
[image]

[image: image2]

Comment: Start Docker. It needs to be running in order for these commands to work.

Comment: check your docker service is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

Running docker comments require the docker daemon (service) to be running.